# App crashes when downloading from appstore

Tags: cocoa-touch, crash, runtime-error

My app running well when running through xcode. After apple submited my app i discovered it crushes on the user's devices. The bug on terminal is:

: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CPTMutableNumericData setDataType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x21606e90'

I know I use this class in CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h.

1.How can i solve it?

2.Why it is happens only when user download it (Also me, as a user) and not crush when running through xcode?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you only tested your app using development builds. Before submitting to the app store you want to test the release build using Adhoc deployment. This lets you test the version you will end up sending to Apple.

For now you need to run your app so it crashes on your own device. Then connect the device to your computer with Xcode running. Go to the Organizer window and select the Devices tab. Click on the Device Logs section near the top left corner. After some updating you should see a crash log for your app at the time you just made it crash. Use the crash log to determine where in your app it is crashing.

Comment: This is exactly what i did. I added the exception from the deivce terminal to my question. Now i need an answer to my question :)

Comment: P.S. In the device log i didn't find an informative data. Just the error code and stuff like that

Comment: Was the crash log properly symbolicated? You need to ensure the crash report is symbolicated so you can exactly where in the code your app crashed.

Comment: I solve it :) I needed to add -objc to other linker flag (I did it only to debug and not to release and adhoc) I tested the app adhoc as you explained me and everything good now. Now i can submit it again in app store. Thanks :)